# Outlining a proof without nesting itemize environments

Tags: lists, enumerate

When writing proofs, I frequently find it helpful to outline how I will go about proving before I actually prove it. Currently, I do so as shown in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    Every square is a rectangle, but not all rectangles are squares.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
\hfill
\begin{enumerate}[{We prove:}]
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
    all squares are rectangles and
\item
    not all rectangles are squares.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Proof here.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Which gives the output:

[image: MWE Output]

Which is more or less what I want the result to look like. However, this has the problem of ``eating'' two of my four list nestings, meaning I can only nest this twice (for long, involved proofs I have had to nest three outlines in the past, and I do not see it as out of the question that one day I shall desire to use four).

I have attempted to get around this with `tabular` but you cannot put the `enumerate` environment inside of `tabular` (to my knowledge), and I'm not really sure how else to go about it. Any suggestions?

Edit: the main problem I have with my current ``solution" is that the code is incredibly ugly in my opinion, in addition to the problem of nesting limitations. For this reason, I would like a solution that avoids nesting lists, although if that's the only workaround, I will certainly make do.

Comment: There is an putlines package, but it only goes 4 levels.

Comment: Why do you nest them in the first place? Why not just bring the `Proof here` bit out of the list environment?

Comment: not necessarily relevant to the question, but recommended with `amsthm`: to go to a new line when proof starts with a list, use `\leavevmode'; to place the qed box at the end of the last line (and avoid the possibility that it can be pushed over to a new page, all by itself), insert `\qedhere` before `\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: @cfr, That was a mistake, I brought the `proof here` bit out, but that doesn't change the problem with nesting lists when I'm making my outline.

@barbarabeeton: I know about `\qedhere`, but as it is an MWE I decided to omit it. I am not familiar with `leavevmode` though, what advantage does that provide over `\hfill`?

Comment: @AbeSchulte -- actually, almost anything that causes tex to enter horizontal mode will (usually) work.  the tricky cases are when a theorem has a long optional heading and it's just long enough to reach the right margin.  there may not be room for more space to be added, so an extra blank line, or an improvident break in the heading might occur.  `\leavevmode` doesn't add anything to the line that will change the current position.  it just changes the mode so that `\begin{<list>}` will be able to make the desired transition.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I could have done with knowing that yesterday... ;).

Comment: @AbeSchulte To be honest, I'm not sure what kind of solution you are looking for at this point. What would your eyes consider less ugly than nested lists? (Personally, I find tabulars a lot uglier in terms of the code, so clearly my eyes see differently from yours.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumitem` allows you to create enumerated environments with greater depth (up to 10 at least, I think):

[image: 5 levels]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myenum}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[myenum]{label=\arabic*}
\begin{document}
  \begin{myenum}
    \item level 1
    \begin{myenum}
      \item level 2
      \begin{myenum}
        \item level 3
        \begin{myenum}
          \item level 4
          \begin{myenum}
            \item level 5
          \end{myenum}
        \end{myenum}
      \end{myenum}
    \end{myenum}
  \end{myenum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see my edit (this is why I upvoted your answer but did not accept it).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have some nicer looking code, define a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{proofoutline}[1]
{\begin{enumerate}[{#1}]\item\begin{enumerate}}
{\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}\par\noindent}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Every square is a rectangle, but not all rectangles are squares.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
  \hfill
    \begin{proofoutline}{We prove:}  
      \item
        all squares are rectangles and
      \item
        not all rectangles are squares.
    \end{proofoutline}
  Proof goes here
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I currently am doing that, however, I still feel that this being LaTeX, there must be a more elegant solution than that. That being said, I (obviously) don't have such a solution available.

Comment: What do you mean with  _not elegant_? Using `enumerate` to indent the listing and to set the short phrase?